Babel preventing deploy on render.com
Hi no matter what I do render will not successfully build. It was working fine a few days ago but now babel is acting up again
I have tried deleting node modules, npm i multiple times and npm install @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object --save-dev
Nothing works.
Everything works fine in local.

